# Android App crashed and showing a white blank Screen

Tags: java, android, calculator

Note: Sorry if my problem may be really easy to fix, I'm a total beginner in this, I literally started learning this just 2 days ago.

So anyway, I'm making this basic calculator app for androids.  I built the .apk and sent it to my phone but it just shows a blank white screen and then it crashes. Here's the xml code and the java code:

```
     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/numbs" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:text="Calculator"
    android:textColor="#E11608"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:background="#000000"

    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/value1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:hint="Type in your next value"

    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/value2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="148dp"
    android:hint="Type in your first value"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:text="+"
    android:layout_gravity="center|left"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/minus"
    android:text="-"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/divide"
    android:text="÷"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/multiply"
    android:text="×"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:onClick="onClick"
/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:text="Your answer should display here"
    android:textColor="#E11608"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"

/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Java code:

```
      package com.Drift.app;

    import android.app.*;
    import android.os.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.view.View.*;
    import android.view.*;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {

int val1;
int val2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    work();

    }




public void work() 
{
    //create parameter for add button
    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    Button multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
    Button minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    Button divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id. title);

    final TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id. answer);
    final EditText value1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. value1);
    final EditText value2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. value2);

    val1 = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
    final Integer val1 = new Integer(value1.getText().toString());

    val2 = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());
    final Integer val2 = new Integer(value2.getText().toString());

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 + val2));
        }
    });
    multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 * val2));
            }
        });

    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 - val2));
            }
        });

    divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 / val2));
            }
        });

}


    }
```

Sorry for not commenting much. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong or maybe propose a better code. P.s sorry again if nearly everything here is wrong but like I said, I'm a total beginner. Thanks.

Okay, thanks for the answers this is is what I ended up with

```
      package com.Drift.app;

    import android.app.*;
    import android.os.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.view.View.*;
    import android.view.*;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
   {

int val1;
int val2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    work();

    }




public void work() 
{
    //create parameter for add button
    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    Button multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
    Button minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    Button divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id. title);

    final TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id. answer);
    final EditText value1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. value1);
    final EditText value2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. value2);


    if(value1.getText()!=null)
        {val1 = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());}


    if(value2.getText()!=null)
        {val2 = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());}



    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 + val2));
        }
    });
    multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {


                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 * val2));
            }
        });

    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 - val2));
            }
        });

    divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)

            {

                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 / val2));
            }
        });


}


    }
```

But it's still giving me a blank white page, I'm using gradle by the way

---

Here's the Android manifest file

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Drift.app" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/calc"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post your logcat.....

Comment: did your MainActivity is declared in your manifest file ?

Comment: share you android manifest and logcat. crash should not happen if activity is declared in manifest as you have not called setText() method yet from anywhere.

Comment: add this line to top of your xml file...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: check my editted answer

Comment: try the xml which i have pasted it should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #51: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
> ```

All views must have `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` defined. At least your `Button`s don't have either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check EditText value before use it :

```
if(value1.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
    val1 = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
 }
 if(value2.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
    val2 = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());
 }
```

Comment: @Drew,please remove space when find view by like : R.id. title to R.id.title

Answer (score 0):

It is a probably a problem with a parsing. You are getting value from empty editText. You should not do that in on create method. You should check if value2 and value1 are null before using it.

```
if(value2.getText()!=null){val2 = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());}
```

Comment: What you're trying to said?

Comment: Empty value cannot be parseable. 
You are trying to get value before user set it. So that is your problem. You should get that value in your onClicks

Answer (score 0):

here is the full working code. i have executed this and its working fine.

ur activity

```
public class MainAvtivity extends Activity {

    int val1;
    int val2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seekbar);

        work();

    }

    public void work() {

        // create parameter for add button
        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        Button multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        Button minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        Button divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        final TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        final EditText value1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value1);
        final EditText value2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value2);



        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!"".equals(value1.getText().toString())) {
                    val1 = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
                }

                if (!"".equals(value2.getText().toString())) {
                    val2 = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());
                }
                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 + val2));
            }
        });
        multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!"".equals(value1.getText().toString())) {
                    val1 = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
                }

                if (!"".equals(value2.getText().toString())) {
                    val2 = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());
                }
                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 * val2));
            }
        });

        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!"".equals(value1.getText().toString())) {
                    val1 = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
                }

                if (!"".equals(value2.getText().toString())) {
                    val2 = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());
                }
                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 - val2));
            }
        });

        divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)

            {
                if (!"".equals(value1.getText().toString())) {
                    val1 = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText().toString());
                }

                if (!"".equals(value2.getText().toString())) {
                    val2 = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText().toString());
                }
                answer.setText(String.valueOf(val1 / val2));
            }
        });

    }

}
```

and u have not specified height and weight in xml.
try this xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/numbs"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="Calculator"
        android:textColor="#E11608"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type in your next value"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/value2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="148dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type in your first value"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="÷" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/multiply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="×" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Your answer should display here"
        android:textColor="#E11608"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Tried your answer, changed setText to work but I'm still having the same problem